# using hibernate with tomcat 7 (without any IDE)

Tags: hibernate

I want to use hibernate using tomcat 7, can you tell me what files to download and from where to use it ? (I dont want to use any IDE like netbeans or myeclipse)

Answer (score 3):

These are just some on top of my head

- Java EE API jars (JSP, servlet, etc)
- Hibernate jars
- Your DBMS driver jar (eg: mysql-connector-java)
- Datasource connection pooling jar (eg: commons-dbcp)
- Logging jar (eg: log4j)
- Unit testing jar (eg: JUnit)

Hopefully you decided to use some package management tool such as Maven in which case you can just search for those jars on http://search.maven.org

Also since you did not mention it, hopefully you also decided to use some web framework such as JSF / Spring.

IDE to programmers are like mechanical tools for carpenters, so try considering the merits and benefits before blindly avoiding it :)